# --ignore-gpu-blacklist command line in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, crosswalk

I want to use the "--ignore-gpu-blacklist" command line on Crosswalk in Android Studio.

It says I must write "--ignore-gpu-blacklist" in a "xwalk-command-line" file in "assets" folder.

But I have no "assets" folder. It seems to me that this folder was used to be used in older IDEs but not anymore in Android Studio. So I searched for where is this folder supposed to be, and I got several different paths... I am not sure that it is supposed to still work this way with Android Studio anyway.

I searched in *XWalkPreferences.setValue(XWalkPreferences.* and  *xWalkWebView.getSettings()*. with no luck.

So, how to make Crosswalk ignore the gpu blacklist in Android Studio, does anybody know ?